# Create side border with a text

Tags: border

I want to achieve the following design for my page border.

I am aware of the `mdframe` package to do a regular border and also of the

```
usepackage{rotating}

\begin{turn}{-90}Test 90\end{turn}
\begin{turn}{270}Test 270\end{turn}
```

But I can't find a way to mix them both to have a border with a text sideways.

How can I make the following page border?

Thank you

[image: What I want to achieve]

Comment: The text should be at the text margin? Outside of it?

Comment: I've updated the image to contain some example text. The text should be at the margin of the document.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example we can compile as a basis for answering.

Comment: @Alenanno Do you know why Christian deleted his answer? Because it is within the text block?

Comment: Do you want the whole page framed? One page? All pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use [tikz-page](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-page):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-page}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\newcommand{\tikzpagelayout}{
  \node [red, rotate=90] (t) at (page.left north) {MYTEXT};
  \draw (t) -- (page.left south);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \lipsum[1-9]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]